# Giving up ownership of a memory without releasing it by shared_ptr

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, make-shared

Is there a way I can make the shared pointer point to a different memory location without releasing the memory.pointed by it currently

Please consider the code:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    int *p = new int();
    *p = 10;
    int *q = new int();
    *q = 20;

    boost::shared_ptr<int> ps(p);

    // This leads to a compiler error
    ps = boost::make_shared<int>(q);

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    std::cout << *q << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the negative votes around the question.
Smart pointers in C++ are not easy concepts to grasp and get your head around for commoners. It is not like program not compiling, keyword missing etc. 

The question is small with a working piece of code. What else is expected for people asking questions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Of course you can release and reattach, while changing the deleter to a no-op

To be honest, it looks like you'd just want

```
ps = boost::make_shared<int>(*q);
```

Prints ([live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faaf1b870a78d2f5)):

```
0
20
```

Comment: With the statement above there will be a leak right for q if I do not explicitly free it ?

Comment: No. The shared pointers will both adequately free their owned resources on destruction/re-assignment

Comment: I ran the code under valgrind. It said invalid read of size 4 at :
std::cout << *p << std::endl;

and said definetly leaked 4 bytes

Comment: @gudge Oh, aha, I've misread the `std::cout` lines (why would you be doing that, by the way? You explicitly re-assign `ps`, so obviously `p` is dangling. I supposed you did `std::cout << *ps` and `std::cout << *qs` there. And since you never free `q` that's definitely leaked.

Comment: Please tell us _what you're trying to achieve_ (not /how/). So we can give a useful answer

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

I want to use ps for operations on p and then use it for operations on q.

I do not wish to re declare another shared_ptr for q.

I should be able to use p even after ps is not pointing to p.

Comment: That's not what shared_ptr is for. End of story. Rethink the logic.